# Need help in sonatype nexus advance search

Tags: nexus

I have a requirement to implement the advance search in sonatype nexus. Can I create the custom keyword to search an artifacts in Nexus? As an example I am looking for all the artifacts uploaded by user "X". In the same way I may have different key to search the artifacts.

Can someone please give me a pointer?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Hi there, what version of Nexus are you using?

Comment: I am using Nexus OSS 3.x

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with Nexus Repository Manager 3. The user who uploaded an artifact is saved but not to metadata currently. You may file an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS to express interest in this functionality, however.